# Do Android Facebook 4.2 API provide Email ID & Mobile Number?

Tags: android, facebook

Is it possible to get the email id of the person who login using facebook in our app?
Just checked out and found everything other than email id as JSON & Graph Response.

```
{"id":"1xxxxxxxxxxx","first_name":"xxxxxxx","timezone":5.5,"verified":true,"name":"xxxxxxxx","locale":"en_US","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/xxxxxxxxxxx\/","last_name":"xxx","gender":"xx","updated_time":"2014-06-26T06:06:41+0000"}
```

Sample code used is below, from the developer website of facebook..

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                        handlePendingAction();
                        updateUI();

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        // String email = object
                                        // .getString("email");
                                        System.out.println(object.toString()
                                                + " :user email: "
                                                + response.toString());

                                    }

                                });                         
                        request.executeAsync();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE) {
                            showAlert();
                            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                        }
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                                && exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                            showAlert();
                            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                        }
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    private void showAlert() {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this)
                                .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                                .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the logged user email as follows , But note that ,

1. They do not guaranteed you will get an email address read here .
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-public_profile
2. In some cases, though user has provided an email, it will not come through request, if the email is not valid.
3. You must request the "email" permission when you log the user in. Even if your app has the email permission, it will not always return an email address, so your app should not rely on that field always having a value as following way.

LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));

Comment: you meant this ...LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));

Comment: yes for getting email you need to add that statement in your code and also try with other facebook ids also.

Comment: As users you are testing have an email address associated with their account so for that users they are displaying the email and not for others  .@Exceptional Thanks also to reply and response on my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80632/discussion-between-rajan-bhavsar-and-exceptional).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add permission of "email".

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
    "publish_actions", "email", "user_birthday","read_stream", "user_photos"
};


LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS );
```

Comment: where to add this PERMISSIONS array?

Comment: 'publish_actions' crashes app.... When i remove it, its running good and fetched the email.....

Comment: is there anything for phone number in facebook api?

Comment: Yes, but for Phone number, user photos and something more. You need to submit your app to facebook for review. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: If answer is help full then, kindly mark as correct.

Comment: got email id for only one account.. Rest all accounts not showing emails

Comment: For all email ids you need to submit your app to facebook for permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to request the permissions and then something like this should work:

```html
public void retrieveEmailUsingGraphAPI(final AccessToken accessToken) {
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
    if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.has(EMAIL)) {
      try {
        String userEmailFromFacebook = jsonObject.getString(EMAIL);

      } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
        LogE(TAG, "FacebookGraphJSONCallback onCompleted ", jsonException);
      }
    } else {
      LogE(TAG, "An error happened in the GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback the jsonObject is null");
    }
  }  
});

  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields", EMAIL);
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
}
```

EMAIL is a string = "email".

Comment: Which Api are you using?, This snippet might need a little upgrade, because it changed a little bit between oldest SDK versions and newest ones.

Comment: its okiee... I fixed it up by adding permission in the other way round. thanks